# Drupal 7 - Content categorization

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, multilingual

I am developing a multi-country and multi-lingual website using Drupal. I am relatively new to Drupal (this is my first project on it).

My client will have multiple country sites (**www.example.com/uk/**, **www.example.com/bg/**, **www.example.com/fr**). What i need is to be able to tag content to a particular country in Drupal and to also have that content then appear on the relevant site. A use case is below:

> The user creates a page called *about* and tags it to the country Bulgaria (bg). They then navigate to **www.example.com/bg/about**, to view the page.

I am also using the Multilingual - Internationalization module ([Link to module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n)). So on top of the above the user will also tag content to a particular language. A use case is below:

> The user creates a page called *about* and tags it to the country Bulgaria (bg), they also select the language as being English. They then navigate to **www.example.com/bg/uk/about**, to view this page.

I have tried many modules etc but to no avail so far. Some things to bare in mind below:

> - This is based on a Drupal 7 install on a local server
> - There is no scope to change the URL structure
> - www.example.com will be their primary groups website which will link through to the international versions

Any guidance or solutions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may make sense to try using the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og/) module to create the 'multi-site' aspect of this. It'll give you more separated sites than tagging alone.

You can make all your groups (countries) be global (in the organic groups default scenario, groups can either be globally visible or visible only to their members).  Then when one of your editors is creating a page, they'd have to select which group that page should belong to, rather than use a tag to segregate country-specific content.

Groups are a good solution, I think, because then, each group (country) can have its own independent menus, using the [og_menu](http://drupal.org/project/og_menu) module, so you can really set them up to look like their own independent little sites.

Once that's set up (and it will take you a while, because there's a steep learning curve with using Organic Groups), you can do the translations independently of which group a page exists in.  I'm assuming the translation stuff is working fairly well with the Multilingual - Internationalization module.

If you use the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, you can set up your url rules to automatically behave the way you want (i.e. with bg for the 'Bulgaria' group, etc).  I actually don't have that setup for my site using Organic Groups, but there are various discussions on how to do that, and I'm just citing one of them here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/organic-groups-group-content-types-and-pathauto

I hope this helps a little....

Comment: Very good answer, helped me very much. I used Organic Groups to get the multi-site functionality (www.example.com/bg etc) and then used taxonomy's for the languages, which after setting up pathauto ([node:group_group]/[node:field-tags]/[node:title] as the default path pattern) works greats. Thanks.